Is there any way to make a Linux ELF binary have an optional shared library dependency without dlopen()?
I have an application that wants to use a shared library (libwayland-client.so) if it is available, but needs to still run even if it is not available.  The usual way to implement this is to use dlopen() and dlsym() to read the shared library manually, but this requires writing a bunch of glue code and prevents me from using the development headers directly.  Is there any way to mark a shared library dependency as optional in an ELF binary in a way that the ELF loader can understand?
Note that this is different from marking a symbol from a shared library as optional (this can be done by marking it as a weak symbol).  I'm asking about how to make the entire library dependency weak.
Note also that this is not about build-time dependencies - I'm fine with depending on the shared library at build time, but I don't want to force my users to have that shared library on their machines.
(In my specific situation, I want my application to support both X11 and Wayland, but to properly support Wayland, it needs to make a few calls to libwayland-client.so.  However, I want to avoid shipping a separate binary for pure X11 users.)

You could check if Implib.so is suitable for your requirements.


Is there any way to make a Linux ELF binary have an optional shared library dependency without dlopen()?

The flavor of ELF used by Linux does not have a way to flag shared-library dependencies as optional (and I would be surprised if any other flavor did, either).

The usual way to implement this is to use dlopen() and dlsym() to read the shared library manually,

That's one way.  But if you need more than a small handful of symbols from the dlopen()ed library then it's unfun.

but this requires writing a bunch of glue code and prevents me from using the development headers directly.

If you support two different display systems for the same program then you already have a bunch of glue code, and you can leverage that.  How hard that is depends on how well factored your current code is, but a reasonably good way forward would be to put all the X11 code in one shared lib, all the Wayland code in another, and make each one implement the same API by which the rest of the program accesses it.  You must already have something at least somewhat along these lines.
You do not necessarily need to use dlopen() to access those display-system-specific libraries.  Since they provide alternative implementations of the same API, you can instead

provide alternative versions of the executable that differ only in which of those libraries they link.

give the two libraries the same SONAME. Then control which is used at runtime by manipulating the program loader's search path, or by preloading the one you want, or similar.


... or perhaps another, similar alternative.  Any of those might benefit from a wrapper script that hides the details of getting the program started correctly for the chosen execution environment.
